# Any way to temporary hide wire frame in edit mode (2.80)?

Tags: wireframe

I would like to be able to toggle wire frame visibility off and on without exiting edit mode, to be able to see the surface better, but without changing the camera's rotation origin (using rotate around selected option). When I exit edit mode, the camera rotates around the object's origin, which makes it a pain to check out small areas on large objects.

Thanks for any advice,
Robert

Answer (score -1):

You can just press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>. Also you can customize it as you want in preferences.

Comment: Doesn't this just enter wire frame mode? I'm looking for a way to actually hide the wires for a brief moment in between edits, to preview the surface at different angles, then go back to normal. My usual answer for this is to exit edit mode, but the camera rotation arc changes dramatically with large objects, which makes rotating around the edited point very tricky sometimes.

Comment: @Robert I think he means Alt + Shift + Z, which toggles show layerss on/off. It does what you want.